# Collecting together data in columns... and knowing if it goes wrong

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning

I have data in a rather stupid format, and I want to make it more sensible.

I have a number of columns that hold the answers to a question, say "What's your favourite food?"

```
      Bolognese    Chips    Salad    Burgers
0                  Chips
1     Bolognese
2                                    Burgers
3                                    Burgers
4                  Chips
```

First of all, I'd some advice on how to collapse these columns into a single column:

```
      Fav food
0     Chips
1     Bolognese
2     Burgers
3     Burgers
4     Chips
```

The answers in these columns are meant to be mutually exclusive, so there shouldn't be any row with two answers in it. What's the best way to be sure? Do I just see if the code for collapsing the columns throws up an error? Should I check for exclusivity across the columns before I collapse them? Is there an accepted way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `max` on rows with `axis=1`

```
In [986]: df.max(axis=1)
Out[986]:
0        Chips
1    Bolognese
2      Burgers
3      Burgers
4        Chips
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need first [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) if `NaN` in `df` and then `apply` `join` or [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
print (df.fillna('').apply(''.join, axis=1))
0        Chips
1    Bolognese
2      Burgers
3      Burgers
4        Chips
dtype: object

print (df.fillna('').sum(axis=1))
0        Chips
1    Bolognese
2      Burgers
3      Burgers
4        Chips
dtype: object
```

Another solution with [`first_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html) - get values from column names:

```
print (df.apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index(), axis=1))
0        Chips
1    Bolognese
2      Burgers
3      Burgers
4        Chips
dtype: object
```

Comment: Excellent! I'll give this a shot.

Comment: The first_valid_index method seemed to be the easiest to apply. It worked out perfectly, so thanks!

I guess the question now is: what a happens if there are two answers in the row? If just takes the first one?

Comment: Ya, it is always hard choose one answer if 2 perfect answer ;) Glad can help you! Good luck!